# Converting VarChaer Ids to BigInt in SQL without a case statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to convert IDs with characters such as 'VS23333Hg87808' to BigInt so I can have this on the same column as the other ids that are simply BigInt and I tried

Try_Convert(BIGINT, id) as set_id

But that did not seem to solve the error.

My question is do add the above query to the id I want to convert only or to all the ids?

Comment: You can't just convert any text to a number. What you posted isn't a number at all. What number do you expect to get out of that string?

Comment: What's the full query and your intended output? `TRY_CONVERT(BIGINT, id)` is going to "work", in the sense that it will yield `NULL` for the value `'VS23333Hg87808'`, but of course that may not be appropriate for your use case.

Comment: *"But that did not seem to solve the error."* What error are you getting? `Try_Convert(BIGINT, id) as set_id` with a value like `'VS23333Hg87808'` won't return an error, just the value `NULL`, so if yo *are* getting an error it isn't in relation to that expression. What "bigint" value are you expecting from the value `'VS23333Hg87808'` anyway? Integer values don't have letters, so the value being a `bigint` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this code

```
CAST(id AS bigint)
```

this should be work